# severe slowdown in a population genetics algorithm using C++ OpenMP: memory management problem?

Tags: c++, openmp, genetics, population

I have a question about optimization in OpenMP that I think involves the organization of memory. My code runs population genetics for a group of N genomes in parallel. A "Genome" is a vector of "Xomes" (chromosomes), which are themselves lists of mutant "Alleles" - the structures are shown below, redacted a bit to keep things simple (I'm working in C++).

**Genome class :**

```
class Allele {
public:
    int x;
    int t;

    Allele() {}
};


class Xome : public list<Allele> {
public:
    char t;
     int L;

    Xome() {}
};


class Genome : public vector<Xome> {
public:
//  location :
    double x;
    double y;

//  sex :
    char t;

    Genome() {}
};


typedef list<Genome> Genome_list;
```

In the population genetics loop, organisms (Genomes) disperse on a landscape, find mates, interbreed and create offspring. Offspring are formed from the parent Genomes in the list x and placed in a buffer, x_buf, as shown below (see "Master loop", again significantly redacted for clarity).

**Master loop :**

```
//  parent Genomes :
Genome_list x;


//  initialize x with N Genomes (N=10,000)


//  offspring Genome buffer :
vector<Genome_list> x_buf(n_threads);


for (int generation=0; generation!=N; ++generation) {


#pragma omp parallel
{
//  disperse Genomes in the Genome_list x
}


#pragma omp parallel
{
    int id;

    id=omp_get_thread_num();

//  select mates from x, mutate, put offspring Genomes in x_buf[id]
}


//  clear parent list :
x.clear();


//  splice offspring to parent list :
int i;
i=0;
for ( ; i!=(int) y.size(); ++i) {
{
    x.splice(x.end(),x_buf[i]);
}


} //  end master loop
```

At the end of each iteration of the loop, the parent Genome list x is cleared, and the offspring Genomes in x_buf are spliced into x to become the new parent population.

As the program continues, Genomes accumulate mutations (new Alleles) which causes the program to slow down, obviously. However, I'm finding that even routines that have nothing to do with the memory size of a Genome (e.g the "dispersal" section of the master loop, which only involves changing the values of Genome member variables x and y) get slower as well, even to the point where using, say, two threads takes just as long (in CPU time) as using one thread after about 3000 iterations.

I remember someone mentioning to me a long while back that I should allocate memory for my Genome lists **within an omp parallel block**; Somehow this was supposed make it easier for the cores to look-up the Genome list data. Anyways, I'm not sure why the code is slowing down. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There really isn't enough code here for us to judge how things go wrong. However, two things to observe: 1. It is highly unusual to inherit from std containers. I'd recommend using composition. 2. If your real Allele class is not much larger, list is a poor container and can explain some of the slowdown over time with its poor cache handling and high allocation overhead. You are probably better off constructing new ```std::vector<Allele>``` instead of splicing existing lists.

Comment: Thanks @Homer512. I have some questions: 1. by inherit, you mean the splice operation that transfers offspring Genomes in x_buf to x, Correct?  2. Did you mean std::vector<Genome>?

Comment: @Homer512 continued . . Anyways, I'm aware of the problems with C++ lists, but my problem is that I have to insert new Alleles (mutations) into Xomes (lists of Alleles) every iteration. This would be very inefficient for vector<Allele> since all elements to the right of the inserted Allele would need to be shifted one unit to the right. I could use fixed length vector<Allele>'s of size=total length of an Xome and then modify the type values of Alleles (say t=1 for mutated, and t=0 for non-mutated), but that would incur a lot of copying since Xomes in my model can be 10k to 100k long.

Comment: @Homer512 continued . . The idea is that by only saving the mutated loci in a chromosome (i.e. in a list of Allele's) the code would run faster than if I save all loci, and change the type values of loci that get mutated.

Comment: 1. You are making efficiency arguments without having measured. So we don't believe your argument for using `list` unless you show proof. 2. "shifting to the right" is not necessary if you append. Can you sort afterwardw? 3. Inserting and such is hard to do in parallel. You should let each thread build up a local data structure, and then merge them.

Comment: If you have to iterate the Allele list even just once to find random insertion/deletion points, creating a new vector would be faster. From our POV all we see is a very suspect data structure and no code (even pseudo-code) to judge its use. If you can show simplified code, a minimum reproducible example, we can give better advise

Comment: I see. Well, Allele lists are being iterated over in a number of different functions to e.g. compute genetic distance between Genomes, etc. From what both of you have said, it seems that using lists of Alleles is very inefficient, and that vector<Allele> with sorting should be used instead. I can include more detailed code, but the "comments" here allow very limited space, so I guess I will need to create another "question".

Comment: PS I found a good benchmark of C++ std::list versus std::vector and I think I understand all your comments better now (see https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/11/cpp-benchmark-vector-vs-list.html). Many thanks.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to edit your question. You can make a new question and delete this one if you think this one may have gone stale and people passed up on it. But at least us commenters will probably see the edited question, especially if you @ us in a comment once you did

Comment: @Homer512 Thanks, I didn't realize I could edit so long after submitting a question. I revised my Genome class to use vector<Allele> and compared the performance of certain parallel operations in my code to the old list<Allele> version. For large lists of Genomes (N=10,000), using vector<Allele> leads to a 4-5 fold improvement over list<Allele>. Also, CPU time increases linearly with N for the vector<Allele> version, and decreases roughly linearly with the # of threads. So, tentatively at least, it looks like the use of list<Allele> was the main problem.